# Some conceptual questions on solving differential equations

Tags: calculus, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

When we went to solve a differential equations -

1. ) by method of variations parameters or undetermined coefficients or any other process why do we need a non zero trial solution $y=e^{mx}$ for the reduced equations of the given equation? Why do we take particularly an exponential functions not the other functions?
2. ) and when we made the equations reduced why do we make it's R.H.S $0$ ?

Comment: $e^{x}$ is proportional to its derivative and so can be factored from each term after differentiation and cannot itself equal zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the ODE is $p(\frac{d}{dx})y(x)=f(x)$ with a polynomial $p$ with constant coefficients, then setting $y(x)=e^{mx}u(x)$ gives
$$
\frac{d}{dx}y(x)=e^{mx}\bigl(u'(x)+mu(x)\bigr)
$$
and consequently
$$
p\Bigl(\frac{d}{dx}\Bigr)y(x)=e^{mx}p\Bigl(\frac{d}{dx}+m\Bigr)u(x)
$$
Now if $m$ is a root of $p$ then $p(\frac{d}{dx}+m)=q(\frac{d}{dx})\frac{d^k}{dx^k}$ where $k$ is the multiplicity of the root, so that the order of the ODE can be reduced by integrating $k$ times the right side $e^{-mx}f(x)$.

---

And why use exponentials in general -- They occur naturally in the integration of linear ODE of order 1 with constant coefficients, which translates also to the linear factors of higher order ODE of that type.

Comment: And the 2nd one?

Comment: That is equivalent to solving $p(m)=0$, i.e., finding the roots of the characteristic polynomial.